# Fusion algorthm: how many DoF for the gyroscope?

Tags: accelerometer, gyro, algorithm, kalman-filter, inclination

The gyro data output will be fed to an Extended Kalman Filter and fused with data output from an accelerometer. my goal is to measure tilt angle over one axis. Do I need a 3 DoF gyro or will a 1 DoF suffice ?

Comment: It depends. Is what you are measuring constrained in all other axes and only moves in one, or is it free and you only want to measure one?

Comment: I am afraid it is free, relatively. There will be shaking and vibrations in all three axes, but actual tilt in just one axis.